# Dynamically created classes not available when using 'nuxt build' - tailwindcss nuxtjs

Tags: nuxt.js, tailwind-css, postcss

I have a nuxtjs project that I use with tailwindcss.

In that project I generate classes on the fly for negative margins like so:

```html
<div class="mins-1" :class="['-mt-'+ m1*8]"></div>
```

The entire project works fine locally, but if I run `nuxt build; nuxt start;` it gets compiled without errors but none of the dynamic classes seem to work.

So I finally found out that the `nuxt build` process does some ***css tree shaking***, and since these classes are not included anywhere in the dom, they are not included in the css build process.

To test this I have created a hidden div like so:

```html
<div class="hidden -mt-8 -mt-16 -mt-24 -mt-32 -mt-40 -mt-48 -mt-56 -mt-64 -mt-72 -mt-80">ok needed classes</div>
```

And voila, that will make my project workable after `nuxt build` since now the classes needed are present in the dom and will be included.

This seems very hacky!

**Now to my question:**

What would be the proper way to include dynamically created classes in the build process in a nuxtjs project?

**UPDATED tailwind.config.js (Did NOT work with JIT MODE turned on!)**

```js
const colors = require("tailwindcss/colors")
module.exports = {
  purge: {
    enabled: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    content: [
      'components/**/*.vue',
      'layouts/**/*.vue',
      'pages/**/*.vue',
      'plugins/**/*.js',
      'nuxt.config.js',
      // TypeScript
      'plugins/**/*.ts',
      'nuxt.config.ts'
    ],
    // UPDATE: safelist does NOT work in combination with JIT
    options: {
      safelist: ['mt-0', '-mt-8', '-mt-16', '-mt-24', '-mt-32', '-mt-40', '-mt-48', '-mt-56', '-mt-64', '-mt-72', '-mt-80'],
    }
  },
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        emerald: colors.emerald,
        gray: colors.trueGray,
        cyan: colors.cyan
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: What is your version of tailwind ?

Comment: Latest 2.1.1  unsing @nuxt/tailwindcss 4.0.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try safelist option for PurgeCss config:

```js
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  purge: {
    // Configure as you need
    content: ['./src/**/*.html'],
    // These options are passed through directly to PurgeCSS
    options: {
      // List your classes here, or you can even use RegExp
      safelist: ['bg-red-500', 'px-4', /^text-/],
      blocklist: [/^debug-/],
      keyframes: true,
      fontFace: true,
    },
  },
  // ...
}
```

EDIT: Seems like OP is using [JIT tailwind mode](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode), `safelist` is [not available](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#known-limitations) right now for this mode. The best way to generate needed classes would be placing some stub file like `stub.html` somewhere in your source directory, and then add all the needed classes inside this file so tailwind could preemptively generate styles for them.

**EDIT2:** `safelist` is now available for jit! But it does not support regular expressions. Because no CSS is generated by default, the safelist has to be a list of complete class names. It’s not possible to safelist a regular expression, because there is no pre-generated list of class names to match against that regular expression.

Comment: see my updated tailwind css file with options safelist, that did not work ...

Comment: It won't work if you are using JIT which you did not mention in the post. With JIT the best way you can do right now is to place some stub file like `stub.html` somewhere with all the classes you need to generate in advance

Comment: Ok I removed jit and now it works, great! So it is either fast development and adding a stub file, or removing jit and have a safelist if I understand you correctly?

Comment: Right now yes, but keep an eye on the docs, I'm sure tailwind team will add some way to generate classes for JIT mode too

Comment: Thank you for your TIME to explain the problem!

Answer (score 3):

You can safelist classes with Tailwind CSS version 3.
I use HTML components in my CMS and for that I have safelisted a couple of classes!

```
module.exports = {
darkMode: "class",
content: [
    "./components/**/*.{js,vue,ts}",
    "./layouts/**/*.vue",
    "./pages/**/*.vue",
    "./plugins/**/*.{js,ts}",
    "./nuxt.config.{js,ts}",
],
safelist: [
    'border-l-2',
    'border-blue-500',
    {
        pattern: /(bg|text|border)-(red|green|blue|purple|yellow)-(100|200|300|400|500)/,
    },
    {
        pattern: /(h|w)-(12|16|24|32|48|64|72|96)/,
    },
    'absolute',
    '-mt-9',
    '-ml-9',
    'pl-4',
    'overflow-scroll'
],}
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you're not using tailwind's JIT, give it a look: it will help you during local development and generate only the needed classes.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode

Then, your config file should look something like this

```js
module.exports = {
  mode: 'jit',
 // These paths are just examples, customize them to match your project structure
 purge: [
   './public/**/*.html',
   './src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,vue}',
 ],
 ...
}
```

---

Disclaimer, I did not try it myself (yet) but this should work fine. Even if IMO, dynamic classes are only to be used with JIT enabled.

Comment: I am using jit in nuxtjs config, but it did not help.

Comment: What about the rest (`purge` key containing an array).

Comment: Can you give more debugging details?

Comment: I also believe that you did not fully understand my issue ...

Comment: I did, just did not spent more time digging into the configuration issues. Also, I kinda prefer using `windy`. Glad you found a solution.